# Alert user when tab unfocused in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet using Google Apps Script. Multiple people collaborate on this spreadsheet, and we would not like to get spammed with emails.

I have tried using the Notification API, changing the window title or favicon, and calling window.alert(), none of which have worked.

How can I alert the user to a change in the document when the user has the tab open in the background?

Comment: What is not working with the Notification API ?

Comment: What do you mean with "alert the user"? What kind of changes are you detecting? Also, remember that Apps Script is executed in a server, not in the user's browser.